# can't get routes working ui-router

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, angular-ui-router, pug

I can't really find out what am I doing wrong here. Seems like the script is all good. There's a working plunker I found out http://plnkr.co/edit/7FD5Wf?p=preview. But, when I run my code, it does not even load app.html. It just loads the index page and that's all. Please don't take this otherwise, if I am doing something stupid. I am very new to angularjs and node js. Below is the index.html file generated by jade. Thanks.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="flysolo">
<head ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <title>Home</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body class="flysolo">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="wrapper" autoscroll="false" ui-view></div>
  </div>    

  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui-router.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendors/oclazyload/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/flysolo.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

flysolo.js

```
var deps = [
    'oc.lazyLoad',
    'ui.router',
    'ui.bootstrap'
];

var app = angular.module('flysolo', deps);

app.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}]);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

    $stateProvider.state('app', {
        abstract:true,
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: '/tpls/home/app.html'
    }).state('app.dashboard', {
        url: '/dashboard',
        templateUrl: '/tpls/home/home.html'
    });
}]);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
});
```

app.html

```
<div ui-view-container>
    <div id="content" ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>
</div>
```

home.html

```
<div class="row">
    This is supposed to be home page.
</div>
```

Comment: wait, the plunker you listed isn't the broken code?

Comment: @Claies its a working version. I tried to follow that implementation.

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: Doesn't show any error in the console.

Answer (score 0):

You have AppCtrl defined on the page head, instead you'll need to move that into the body portion of the page so that ui-view is in its scope, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="flysolo">
  <head>
   <title>Home</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body class="flysolo">
    <div class="row" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <div id="wrapper" autoscroll="false" ui-view></div>
    </div>    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui-bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/vendors/oclazyload/ocLazyLoad.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/libs/flysolo.js"></script>
   </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: it would fall in scope even if the controller is defined in body or page head. btw, i tried following your solution, but it didn't work.

Comment: In app.html you have <div ui-view-container>, have you tried using <div ui-view> instead?

Comment: Didn't try. But the thing is that  the script does not load this file at all as it should.